# Open PDF outside Browser

Tags: php

I'm new to PhP and need some help please

I have the following code to open a Staff member's PDF payslip however when it opens it is easy enough for the User to see the path in the address bar and then be able to manipulate the path to see other people's payslips.
This would however not be possible it the PDF file opened outside the Browser (maybe downloading the file and then opening it in Adobe or so).
(There is a login procedure before it gets to this code)
Can someone help with this please?

```
 if(isset($_POST['openpayslip'])){
if(!file_exists('payslips/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.pdf')){
echo "Payslip or function does not exist";
}
if(file_exists('payslips/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.pdf')){
header('Location: payslips/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.pdf');
}
}
```

Comment: If you have users who know the Developer Tools (which are available in every browser) they still will be able to see the URL where the PDF is coming from. The only secure solution is to restrict the access to each PDF file separately.

Comment: Sorry, that would be "security by ofbuscation", and actually a pretty weak attempt. That is _not_ security what you are trying to do. It is _false_ security. In fact it invites everyone to try around. Instead you should think about a _real_ protection. That typically involves some form of authorization strategy. Especially when it comes to sensitive data like payment inside a company you are even legally required to protect that data. At least in most parts of the world.

Comment: If you are new to php and you are handling sensitive data... be very careful! You do not want to expose yourself or your organization to the risk of being hacked and or sued. Good luck and have fun coding though

Answer (score 0):

You load the PDF file into the PHP file and then output it with a PDF header, so that people can only see one file, with some authorisation variables given.

For example, you user name is an uneditable SESSION value (in a perfect world), so you display the payslip with:

`payslip.php`

and in this PHP file you load

```
if(file_exists('payslips/'.$_SESSION['username'].'.pdf')){
    $output = file_get_contents("payslips/".$_SESSION['username'].".pdf");
    header("Content-type:application/pdf");
    print $output;
}
```

This is a VERY rough and sketchy example above, but with this approach you essentially are showing the PDF file through the PHP file so the source material is never revealed directly to the end user.